# PHP cURL Class - Cookies not functioning

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm using the [php-curl-class](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) from [github](https://github.com).

I've sent a few posts to login to a website using `$curl->post("webiste.com", array());` and after returning the data from the response I can verify I login successfully.

My issue lies when using `$curl->get("http://website.com");`.

The PHP cURL class's get() function is not reading the cookies correctly.

My code contains the following at the top of the document:

```
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setCookieFile('cookies.txt');
$curl->setCookieJar('cookies.txt');
```

Is this not enough for the get() function to properly use the cookies?

I can verify the cookies.txt file is created and cookies are printed in the file but they're just not being used 100%.

I know they're not being read correctly because when I use the following code:

```
echo $curl->get("website.com");
```

I can see that I am not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem.

So I added

```
$curl->setCookieFile('cookies.txt');
$curl->setCookieJar('cookies.txt');
```

inside of a function, and I was attempting to use

```
$curl->get();
```

outside of the function. And I only set the cookiejar and cookiefile inside the function, so before the $curl->get(); function, I needed to redeclare the cookiefile & jar.